# Reading a file using webview?

Tags: android, pdf

```
String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+urlPDF;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
startActivity(intent);
```

But it leaves the current activity and it open in google doc url. I want to open it in my current activity in a webview. Please advice and if possible provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
webView.loadUrl(googleDocsUrl);
```

Comment: That i know but its again opening in google doc urlie in new activity.

Comment: i can't understand what you say ?

Answer (score 0):

you should add something like this to your shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {



        if (url != null )) {
             view.getContext().startActivity(
                 new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
             return true;

        }
            if( url.startsWith("http://docs") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                 return false;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_medicalpricing);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return true;
```